# Two Threads are Slowing Each Other C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have 2 Images in Picturebox. When I check the checkbox fans are starting the spinning.
I create two different threads(but they are doing the same job). If I check only one of them it is working with no problem but If I check both of them at the same time they are slowing each other. I want to Threads not affect each other. How can I handle this situation?

[image: Not run]

[image: Freezer Fan running]

[image: Radial Fan running]

[image: Both are running]

```
Thread rotateImageThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RotateImageThreadFunction));
Thread radialFanTurningThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RadialFanTurningThreadFunction));
static ManualResetEvent pauseResumeThreadForFreezerFan = new ManualResetEvent(true);
static ManualResetEvent pauseResumeThreadForRadialFan = new ManualResetEvent(true);
static bool rotateImageRunFlag = false;
static bool radialFanRunFlag = false;
bool startThreadAtStartFlag = true;
bool startThreadAtStartForRadialFanFlag = true;

private void CB_freezer_fan_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cb_freezer_fan.Checked == true)
    {
        StartThreadAtStart();
        pb_FreezerFan.Visible = false;
        pb_FreezerFanRunning.Visible = true;
        setRotateImageRunFlag(true);
        pauseResumeThreadForFreezerFan.Set();
    }
    else
    {
        pb_FreezerFan.Visible = true;
        pb_FreezerFanRunning.Visible = false;
        setRotateImageRunFlag(false);
        pauseResumeThreadForFreezerFan.Reset();
    }
}

private static void RotateImageThreadFunction(object objectToInside)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)objectToInside;
    int rotateAngle = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        pauseResumeThreadForFreezerFan.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
        if (getRotateImageRunFlag() == true)
        {
            rotateAngle = pictureBox.Visible == false ? 0 : rotateAngle;
            pictureBox.Image = RotateImage(global::SimulationInterface.Properties.Resources.FreezerFanRunning1, rotateAngle);
            rotateAngle += 5;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            rotateAngle = (rotateAngle == 360) ? 0 : rotateAngle;
        }
    }
}

public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
{
    //create an empty Bitmap image
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

    //turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    //now we set the rotation point to the center of our image
    gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);

    //now rotate the image
    gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

    gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);

    //set the InterpolationMode to HighQualityBicubic so to ensure a high
    //quality image once it is transformed to the specified size
    //gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    //now draw our new image onto the graphics object
    gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

    //dispose of our Graphics object
    gfx.Dispose();

    //return the image
    return bmp;
}

public void StartThreadAtStart()
{
    if (startThreadAtStartFlag == true)
    {
        rotateImageThread.Start(pb_FreezerFanRunning);
        rotateImageThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        startThreadAtStartFlag = false;
    }
}

private static void RadialFanTurningThreadFunction(object objectToInside)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)objectToInside;
    int rotateAngle = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        pauseResumeThreadForRadialFan.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
        if (getRadialFanRunFlag() == true)
        {
            pictureBox.Image = RotateImageForRadialFan(global::SimulationInterface.Properties.Resources.ventilating_fan, -rotateAngle);
            rotateAngle += 5;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            rotateAngle = (rotateAngle == 360) ? 0 : rotateAngle;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(rotateAngle);
    }
}

private void cb_RadialFan_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangePictureboxImageWithCheckbox(cb_RadialFan, pb_HvacFan, pb_HvacFanRunning);
    if (cb_RadialFan.Checked == true)
    {
        StartThreadAtStartForRadialFan();
        setRadialFanRunFlag(true);
        pauseResumeThreadForRadialFan.Set();
    }
    else
    {
        setRadialFanRunFlag(false);
        pauseResumeThreadForRadialFan.Reset();
    }
}

public static Image RotateImageForRadialFan(Image img, float rotationAngle)
{
    //create an empty Bitmap image
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

    //turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    //now we set the rotation point to the center of our image
    gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);

    //now rotate the image
    gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

    gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);

    //set the InterpolationMode to HighQualityBicubic so to ensure a high
    //quality image once it is transformed to the specified size
    //gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    //now draw our new image onto the graphics object
    gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

    //dispose of our Graphics object
    gfx.Dispose();

    //return the image
    return bmp;
}

public void StartThreadAtStartForRadialFan()
{
    if (startThreadAtStartForRadialFanFlag == true)
    {
        radialFanTurningThread.Start(pb_HvacFanInner);
        radialFanTurningThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        startThreadAtStartForRadialFanFlag = false;
    }
}

public static bool getRotateImageRunFlag()
{
    return rotateImageRunFlag;
}

public static void setRotateImageRunFlag(bool state)
{
    rotateImageRunFlag = state;
}

public static bool getRadialFanRunFlag()
{
    return radialFanRunFlag;
}

public static void setRadialFanRunFlag(bool state)
{
    radialFanRunFlag = state;
}
```

Comment: I see one problem with your code, but it might be unrelated (but then again might not), you're changing UI objects from secondary threads. This needs to be synchronized using `Invoke` method on those UI objects.

Comment: To debug your code, please remove bits from the threads, bit by bit, to figure out what it is that is affecting the other thread.

Comment: Would your code run properly? Using non-ui thread should be not able to change UI. Where you have two non-ui thread to change it. Using Windows.Form.Timer would be better for changing UI, because you don't need to handle thread issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not modify UI in background thread.
If this is winform application, use System.Windows.Forms.Timer.
If this is not winform applicatoin, find the one invoke UI thread for you.

```
// Initial code
var tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
tmr.Interval = 10;
tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
tmr.Enabled = true;


private void Tmr_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  // Rotate cb fan if checked
  // Rotate radial fan if checked
}
```

---

To explain why your two update function is slowing each other, I'll assume your code snippet in post is incomplete. There should be `Invoke` to change control.

1. Invoke is time consuming.
2. You might unconsciously adding the `Thread.Sleep` in `Invoke` which results in your UI thread is sleeping for 10 ms after control is updated. 
   There is two thread, each one update and sleep for 10 ms, so it takes 20 ms to see your control changed. It could be worse than 20 ms.

Comment: I tried this solution and its worked. They are not slowing each other. Thanks! but its not smooth as much as I tried with Threads.

Comment: If you want it to run more smoothly, reduce the interval and using precalculated picture instead of rotating by Graphics. Also search about `DoubleBuffer` which might increase your picture update speed.

Comment: I already tried DoubleBuffer and its not really work. I will search precalculated picture.